# Problema no SOAP do PHP7

Tags: php, soap, php-7, php-5, soapclient

iniciei um projeto utilizando o php 5.6.26 e consegui realizar a comunicação com o servidor do e-frete via SOAP sem problemas.

Essa semana resolvi atualizar o php para a versão 7.0.13, e a comunicação via SOAP parou de funcionar. Fiz varias modificações baseadas em exemplos na internet, mas nada surtiu efeito.

**O código a seguir funciona 100% no php 5.6.26 mas não no php 7.0.13:**

```
$obterOperacaoTransportePdf = [
        'ObterOperacaoTransportePdfRequest' => [
            'Integrador' => 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx', //Hash de referência ao integrador
            'Versao' => '1', //Versão = 1
            'CodigoIdentificacaoOperacao' => 'xxxxxxxxxx/aaaa', //Código de identificação da Operação (CIOT).
            'DocumentoViagem' => ''
        ]
]; 

$options = array(
        'local_cert' => $this->certKEY,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        "style" => SOAP_RPC,
        'connection_timeout' => 15,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => 1
);

$urlWsdl = 'https://sistema.efrete.com:6061/Services/PefService.asmx?wsdl';
$soap = new \SoapClient($urlWsdl, $options);
$data = $soap->ObterOperacaoTransportePdf($obterOperacaoTransportePdf);
```

Retorno quando usado PHP7:

```
[ObterOperacaoTransportePdfResult] => stdClass Object
(
        [Versao] => 1
        [Sucesso] => 
        [Excecao] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Mensagem] => Sistema e-FRETE (www.efrete.com): [Negócio] (Protocolo: 86337) Erro obtendo PDF de operação de transporte: Integrador não cadastrado
            )
        [ProtocoloServico] => 86337
)
```

**No PHP5 retorna o PDF normalmente.**

Em conversa com o pessoal do e-frete, segundo eles, o 'Integrador' não está chegando, então estou pensando que é algo que o php7 está enviando de forma errada...

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para montar de forma diferente para testar? ou se já passou por algo parecido no php7 e resolveu...

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackpt! Você checou se existem diferenças entre as mensagens SOAP enviadas pelas versões 5 e 7 do PHP?

Comment: Olá, Até onde verifiquei está igual. Acredito que o problema deve estar dentro da extensão "php_soap.dll"... Ou, na versão nova do php algo mudou e deve-se adicionar alguma informação a mais....

Comment: Pessoal, resolvi o problema fazendo a chamada de forma diferente: Ao invés de chamar assim: $data = $soap->ObterOperacaoTransportePdf($obterOperacaoTransportePdf);          fiz a chamada assim: $dataResp = $soap->__soapCall($operaration, array($data));